# QT connect no matching function to call to

Tags: c++, function, qt, qobject, qt-connection

I know there are already some threads for this question but I think I made none of the mistakes others did which led to the problem. So here is my code:

```
#include "consolerender.h"

consoleRender::consoleRender(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent) {
    connect(Enviroment::instance, &Enviroment::enviromentChanged,
            this, &consoleRender::renderField);
}
```

And the header:

```
class consoleRender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit consoleRender(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void renderField();

};
```

And the Enviroment.h

```
class Enviroment : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    static Enviroment& instance();
    virtual ~Enviroment();

//stuff...

signals:
    void enviromentChanged();
```

I already tried to do the connect in a separate class. I tried to use the old connect syntax (SIGNAL/SLOT(function)) and I tried it with >>all<< my classes inheriting from QObject but it showed the same error. Also it says something that the function expects 3 arguments but gets 4.  It seems to point at the connect(...renderField). I heard of a solution to just do all of that in the MainWindow class but that is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the instance pointer:

```
connect(&Enviroment::instance(), &Enviroment::enviromentChanged,
        this, &consoleRender::renderField);
```